# Does NSWindowController showWindow Trigger Embedded NSView setNeedsDisplay?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a window with a custom NSView. I use a NSWindowController to load it from NIB in code.

Question: If I send the showWindow message for the NSWindowController, will it also send the setNeedsDisplay message for the embedded custom NSView in the window's hierarchy?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you try it and find out? The `drawRect:` method will definitely be called as part of `showWindow`, if that's what you're wondering about.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert, yes I will try it, but thought I would tap into the mindshare of more experience folks here...

Answer (score 1):

In general you only ever need to send `[self setNeedsDisplay:YES]` when a value used inside `-drawRect` is changed *after* the view appears for the first time. It should always be sent by `self`, other objects should never need to send a `-setNeedsDisplay:` message except to work around a bug or something.

Since `showWindow` is before the window is initially drawn to the screen, you do not usually need `-setNeedsDisplay:`, unless (again) you've found a bug.

If you open the menu item `Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> More Developer Tools...` and search for "graphics", you can download a bundle of tools, one of which is Quartz Debug. Using this debugger, you can make the screen flash yellow whenever the screen is drawn to, and red whenever a screen draw simply re-draws whatever was already visible.

You can use this to find out what parts of the screen are being refreshed too frequently.

Comment: I think your first sentence here serves as a pretty good answer or close to it so far. Thanks.